# Copy vim ctags <C-]> and <C-T>key mapping to <C-Q> and <C-A>

Tags: c, linux, vim, ctags, cscope

I am browsing long source code using vim+cscope+ctags. I find it really cumbersome to always press `<C-]>` and `<C-T>` as the keys are located far apart. I want to copy these key bindings to `<C-Q>` and `<C-A>` so that both the key bindings work in VIM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be :

```
nnoremap <C-q> <C-]>
nnoremap <C-a> <C-t>
```

However I would discourage these mappings because they would cause issues.

- `<C-a>` in vim is used to increment the number under the cursor by 1, `<C-x>` similarly is for decrementing a number under the cursor by 1.

Comment: Additionally Ctrl-Q/Ctrl-S are usually flow control codes used in terminals and may not work every where. So, I changed to <C-m> and <C-n>.

Comment: Note that `<C-m>` is the same as `<Enter>`.

Answer (score 1):

So, what's the problem? Simple normal mode mappings will do:

```
:nnoremap <C-q> <C-]>
:nnoremap <C-a> <C-t>
```

Comment: It's not working. After putting above in my `.vimrc` when I press `<C-]>` it says `-- VISUAL BLOCK --` in vim status line. Other keys are also not working. Interestingly, when I press `<C-T>` over an integer value, the value start increasing.